# How do I pass bind variables to Message Explain text in message catalog?

Tags: peoplesoft

I know that when I use messages from the message catalog, I can use bind variables in the text of the message. For example,

Message Text:

> Employee (%1) has already worked %2% this month.

Description:

> Employees cannot work over %3% for any given month. Decrease percent for row %5 to %4%.

I noticed that when I use `MessageBox`, I can pass a value into the third, fourth, and firth binds, but when I use any other function (`MsgGet`, `MsgGetExplainText`, or `CreateException`), the binds in the explain text are not replaced. I am doing this because I need sometimes stop processing with `Error`, passing in the text from the message catalog (i.e. `Error(MsgGet()`).

---

For example:

Using `MessageBox()`
[image: Binds replaced properly]

Using `Error(MsgGet())`
[image: Binds not replaced]

These are produced from the following, respectively:

```
MessageBox(0, "", 20007, 6, "MESSAGE NOT FOUND: Too many hours. Decrease percentage.", &emplid, Round(&percentInMonth * 100, 0), Round(&workPercentCap * 100, 0), &neededPercent, &rowNumber);
```

And

```
Error (MsgGet(20007, 6, "MESSAGE NOT FOUND: Too many hours. Decrease percentage.", &emplid, Round(&percentInMonth * 100, 0), Round(&workPercentCap * 100, 0), &neededPercent, &rowNumber));
```

How do I get around this problem? I am running PeopleTools 8.54.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 8.54 PeopleBooks for [MsgGetExplainText](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E80738_01/pt854pbh2/eng/pt/tpcl/langref_PeopleCodeBuilt-inFunctionsAndLanguageConstructs_M.html#ubc32e25d-1d1c-4395-bf98-e08de7d68c46), it mentions the following:

> **Note:** This substitution only takes place in message explain text when the MsgGetExplainText function is used. If you use a message box, the parameter substitution will not occur in the explain text.

This is an unclear way of saying that you *can't* do that. This also applies to `MsgGet` and `CreateException`, even though not specified in their docs.

---

However, there *is* a workaround found at [IT Toolbox](http://peoplesoft.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/peopletools-l/problem-with-msggetexplaintext-1493814).

Users in that thread posted something close to the following code as a workaround (adapted here to suit your question):

```
Local string &errorMessage = MsgGet(20007, 6, "MESSAGE NOT FOUND: Too many hours. Decrease percentage.", &emplid, Round(&percentInMonth * 100, 0), Round(&workPercentCap * 100, 0), &neededPercent, 1);
&errorMessage = &errorMessage | Char(10) | Char(10);
&errorMessage = &errorMessage | MsgGetExplainText(20007, 6, "MESSAGE NOT FOUND: Too many hours. Decrease percentage.", &emplid, Round(&percentInMonth * 100, 0), Round(&workPercentCap * 100, 0), &neededPercent, 1);
Local string &temp = MsgGet(0, 0, "");
Error &errorMessage;
```

For whatever reason, the binding of the variables happens after the fact, meaning, if you call `Error` on the return value of `MsgGet`, the result is an error message with the *unbound* parameters.

You need to append the results of `MsgGet` *and* `MsgGetExplainText` onto each other to mimic the functionality of `MessageBox` as above.

Note that the seemingly useless statement `Local string &temp = MsgGet(0, 0, "");` is necessary, otherwise the last line of the message is repeated, but without parameter substitutions:
[image: Repeated explain-text]

This clears away the unbound explain-text returned from `MsgGet` and `MsgGetExplainText`.

---

If you wanted to throw an `Exception` instead, the same principles apply. You need to use the workaround. You can also strip the stack trace from the message if you don't want that displaying to end-users:

```
Local string &errorMessage = MsgGet(20007, 6, "MESSAGE NOT FOUND: Too many hours. Decrease percentage.", &emplid, Round(&percentInMonth * 100, 0), Round(&workPercentCap * 100, 0), &neededPercent, 1);
&errorMessage = &errorMessage | Char(10) | Char(10);
&errorMessage = &errorMessage | MsgGetExplainText(20007, 6, "MESSAGE NOT FOUND: Too many hours. Decrease percentage.", &emplid, Round(&percentInMonth * 100, 0), Round(&workPercentCap * 100, 0), &neededPercent, 1);
Local string &temp = MsgGet(0, 0, "");

rem "Remove" the Stack-Trace;
try
   throw CreateException(0, 0, &errorMessage);
catch Exception &e
   Error &e.ToString( False); rem False means no stack trace;
end-try;
```

---

In addition, it is possible to `extend` the `Exception` class and to substitute bind values in that way. It is a little more complicated, however. Here is an example:

```
class CustomException extends Exception
   method CustomException(&messageSet As integer, &messageNum As integer, &message As string, &substitutions As array of string);
end-class;

method CustomException
   /+ &messageSet as Integer, +/
   /+ &messageNum as Integer, +/
   /+ &message as String, +/
   /+ &substitutions as Array of String +/
   %Super = CreateException(&messageSet, &messageNum, &message);
   Local integer &i;
   For &i = 1 To &substitutions.Len
      %Super.SetSubstitution(&i, &substitutions.Get(&i));
   End-For;
   rem Setting Context to something else replaces the stack trace with whatever text set it to;
   %Super.Context = "";
   %Super.DefaultText = &message;
end-method;
```

To make this work, you can pass in an array of bind variables that you want to substitute into the message and then loop through the array and call `SetSubstitution()` for each variable.

Also, as noted above, if you want the Exception to "throw" like an error message (that is, display the error message *without* a stack trace), you can erase the `Context` of the `CustomException`:

```
%Super.Context = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me -

`&string = MsgGetExplainText(25070, 144, "Error Message", &BINDVARIABLE);
&string1 = MsgGetExplainText(99999, 1, """");
 Error (&string);`